# Command to list all user accounts as well as their last logged in information?

Tags: osx, users

I am using this line of script to return back the list of my user accounts on a Mac via Terminal:

`dscl . list /Users | grep -v '_'`

While it returns the list of all user accounts, I also need for it to list their last logged in information as well.

I have attempted to research what other commands I could pipe in as well, but am unsuccessful.

How to return a list of user accounts on Mac computer as well as the user account's last logged in information next to it?

Comment: What information are you looking for? Just the last time that they logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop over the user accounts and invoke the `last` command.

Here's a little script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read user; do
    if ! last -5 "$user" | grep "^$user"; then
        printf "$user\tno session found\n"
    fi
done < <(dscl . list /Users | grep -v '^_')
```

You could also feed multiple user names to `last` like `last user1 user2`, but you wouldn't get any output unless session data exists for the user.

In the script above option `-5` is used to limit the output to the 5 (last recent) entries and `grep` to make sure each line starts with the user name you're looking for. If no line is found, then `no session found` is printed for the user.

Make sure you have admin rights when you run the script, otherwise the output of `last` will be empty.

Comment: Thanks, the script lists the user account name (e.g. user1, user2, etc.) but I would like to list their real name (John Doe, Jane Doe, etc.). In your script, I changed line 7 to `done < <(dscl . list /Users RealName | grep -v '^_')` which does the trick, however it lists `no session found` for each `RealName` user account. Is there a way to list their real name as well as their most recent last logged in information?

Comment: You could add a line `finger -m "$user" | grep -o 'Name:.*'` before the line starting with `if !...` instead of using `dscl ...RealName`. This prints a line like `Name: John Doe` before the output starts. Would that be okay?

Comment: That works! Thanks again!!